# Can't get logstash to handle JSON file

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to get a JSON file parsed by logstash into elasticsearch. I've read several examples but nothing I've tried seems to work. All I want to do for a start is read the JSON file and convert each key:value pair into the same values in elasticsearch. But when I run `/opt/logstash$ bin/logstash -f ~/logstash-test.conf` with the filter below I just get:

> Logstash startup completed

and nothing appears in elasticsearch. What am I missing?

```
input {
  file {
    type => "json"
    path => ["/home/demo/data.json"]
    start_position => beginning
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => message
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: You have probably processed the file with Logstash at some point in the past, so Logstash is patiently waiting for more data to be appended to the file. `start_position` only matters the first time a file is encountered.

Comment: So how can I check if the data's in elasticsearch and why can't I see it in Kibana?

Comment: If the file has already been processed in logstash, you can get it to be re-processed by deleting the `sincedb` file. See http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#sincedb_path for default location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem turned out to be that my hard drive was almost full so Elasticsearch was reporting that it couldn't save it. Unfortunately this isn't reported from logstash so while the process appears to be working nothing gets saved.

I was also helped by [Magnus Bäck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414355/magnus-b%C3%A4ck)'s comment about how `start_position` wasn't resetting the file, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but the logstash docs for the json filter say:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

Putting quotes around message could maybe fix your issue. Also put quotes around beginning.

Furthermore the path must always be the absolute path, check this too if you set it correctly.

Comment: The [documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration) also says: "Single, unquoted words are valid as strings, too, but you should use quotes." so your suggestion is unlikely to help.

Comment: No, it didn't make any difference.